# Knockout JS - textInput binding update is delayed by one character

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm currently trying to display a message that depends on instant update of the contents of my input text box using knockout.js. the textInput binding seems to work great except it only updates *after* I've already typed one character. On the first character, it says it is not defined.

HTML:

```
 <input id="userResponse" 
                       data-bind="textInput: textInput,
                              hasFocus: responseSelected,
                              ojComponent: {component: 'ojInputText', 
                                            value: userResponse,
                                            rootAttributes: {
                                            style:'font-size:32px; max-width:100%;'}}"
                       autofocus/>
```

JS

```
self.textInput = ko.observable();
self.responseTypeValidation = function (keyCode) {
                oj.Logger.log("input: " +self.textInput());
                if (self.promptMetadata()) {

                    if(self.textInput().match(/[a-z]/))
                    {
                        self.responseErrorMessage("Numbers only");
                    }
                    else {
                       self.responseErrorMessage('');
                    }                      
                }
            };
```

For example when I type "hello" it will throw error saying textInput is undefined on the "h" and then while I type "ello" it does what I actually want it to do (which is display the "numbers only" message). Why would it not be updating on the first input character? Any help figuring this out would be appreciated

EDIT:
Here is my log when the input box reads "he", with the "h" throwing the error and the "e" not yet being read

```
jobCommand.js:81 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
at jobCommandContentViewModel.self.responseTypeValidation (jobCommand.js:81)
at ControllerViewModel.keyDown (jobCommand.js:33)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (appController.js:60)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)


ojcore.js:262 input: h
```

Comment: sounds like there's a timing issue - perhaps `responseTypeValidation` is firing before the input value is actually available to `self.textInput()`?

Comment: How are you calling `responseTypeValidation`?

Comment: I thought so too until I tried putting it in a function which is called each time a key is pressed, the first one is always undefined

Comment: @Michael Best responseTypeValidation is currently in a function that is called every time a key is pressed, and that function is currently working properly. the call is self.responseTypeValidation(keyCode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since using textInput this updates your model immediately on each keystroke or other text entry mechanism (such as cutting or dragging text, which don’t necessarily raise any focus change events).

Therefore:

Solution 1 (Computed):

```
self.Validation = ko.computed(function () {
    if(self.textInput().match(/[a-z]/))
        self.responseErrorMessage("Numbers only");
    else
        self.responseErrorMessage('');
}, self);
```

Solution 2 (subscribe):

```
self.textInput.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if(newValue.match(/[a-z]/))
        self.responseErrorMessage("Numbers only");
    else
        self.responseErrorMessage('');
});
```